# Encompass a wrist or is there an alternative?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

Can **encompass** be used to describe someone "holding" someone's wrist gently, and not actually putting any force/ pressure but just holding or gripping it in a very gentle way?

Answer (score 4):

I would go with ***cradle*** (“to hold gently and protectively”). Otherwise, you could use *hold*, *clasp*, *enfold* or other synonyms, together with an adverb softening their strength (e.g., *hold gently*).

Comment: Does this also work for adults? I don't want to use gently, because I overused it already.

Comment: It certainly works for adults.